# extends and abstract quetsion

Tags: java, android, class, abstract-class

I create a general class called `GeneraFriendsTable`
the code like this:

```
public abstract class GeneralFriendsTable {
    public static String TABLE_NAME;
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_UNAME     + " TEXT, " + ");";
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    }
}
```

I want when extending from this class to force initializing the field `TABLE_NAME`.

for example:

```
public class NewFriendsTable extends GeneralFriendsTable {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "leaved_friends";
}
```

**The main question is:**
will `onCreate()` work correctly using the `TABLE_NAME` in extended class?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: I just need the best way to solve this problem :)

Comment: you can add constructor GeneralFriendsTable(String tname) that will initialize it

Comment: Declaring you variable protected or public you can access it from the extended class. Apart from that you can't reassign value to final variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an abstract function in the superclass to obtain the table name:

```
public abstract class GeneralFriendsTable {

    public abstract String getTableName();

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + getTableName() + ...
    }
}
```

Then implement the function in the concrete subclasses:

```
public class NewFriendsTable extends GeneralFriendsTable {
    public String getTableName() {
        return "leaved_friends";
    }
}
```